# Kernel of a linear operator

Tags: linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Wikipedia:

> If $V$ and $W$ are topological vector spaces such that $W$ is finite-dimensional, then a linear operator $ L: V → W$ is continuous iff ${\frak Ker}(L)$ is a closed subspace of $V$.

The theorem seems pretty general since it doesn't require any specific structure for $W$ and $V$.
So at first glance, it shouldn't hold if $\ \dim W,V = \infty\ $. But what if $V=W=\scr H$, a Hilbert space? Is there some hope?
Maybe not a double implication, but something like:

$L \in {\frak B}({\scr H}) \implies {\frak Ker}(L) \equiv \overline {{\frak Ker}(L)} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any TVS $V,W$ (where $W$ is Hausdorff) we have $L: V\to W$ continuous implies $\text{Ker}(L)$ closed: the kernel of $L$ is the preimage of $\{0\}$, which is closed if $W$ is Hausdorff. Since $L$ is continuous, the preimage of $\{0\}$ is then closed in $V$.

For the other implication a simple counterexample goes as follows: let $(v_n)$ be an ONB (or at least an orthonormal sequence) and define $T v_n:= n v_n$. This operator is unbounded, hence discontinuous, but still has a closed kernel: the trivial subspace.